# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for FirebaseInitProvider with Android Studio in Windows device

Tags: android, windows, android-studio-2.3

When run the app in android emulator crashing the app with Run time exception i.e. **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"**

Running the app with Android studio in Windows Operating system. This crash happening with emulator OS version 4.4, 4.2, 5.0.1, when run the app with emulator OS version 6.0 its working fine.

Enabled multidex

```
defaultConfig {
        .............
        .............   
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

as well Override the attachBasecontex in Application file

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Please help on this to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your manifest in application tag`(where we place activities etc)`

```
 <service android:name="paste your class name here and press ctrl+enter">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: We didn't used any Firebase library in the project yet.
Even though I follow your suggestion still getting the issue